# Angular 2 - EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null browser_adapter.ts

Tags: angular

all ! After update from beta 12 to RC1, I'm facing this issue - and I've no clue what's going on. Does anyone have the solution ?

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null
>   browser_adapter.ts:88 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null
>   browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of nullBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.ts:89ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:53(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:304schedulerFn @ async.ts:131SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ async.ts:117onError @ ng_zone.ts:138onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.ts:90ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233_loop_1 @ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>   browser_adapter.ts:78 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:56(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:304schedulerFn @ async.ts:131SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ async.ts:117onError @ ng_zone.ts:138onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.ts:90ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233_loop_1 @ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>   browser_adapter.ts:78 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:538)
>       at PromiseCompleter.reject (zone.js:515)
>       at eval (application_ref.ts:340)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:323)
>       at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.ts:67)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:322)
>       at Zone.run (zone.js:216)
>       at zone.js:571
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.ts:56)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.ts:57(anonymous function) @ application_ref.ts:304schedulerFn @ async.ts:131SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ async.ts:117onError @ ng_zone.ts:138onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.ts:90ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233_loop_1 @ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>   zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
>   zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null(…)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8519

- maybe you need to update the parameter list of the `transform()` function of a pipe
- you might miss the `emitDecoratorMetadata: true` in your config
- have a circular dependency that is not resolved using `forwardRef()`
- some import that doesn't resolve
- missing `@Injectable()` on a service
- ...

Comment: Yeah..the list are big :) Let me follow your checklist...Btw, I'm attending that thread also.

Comment: The bullets are what I gathered from the thread anyway.

Comment: No lucky :( All services have injectors, emitDecorator is true, pipe updated to : import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'field'})
export class FieldPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, arg:string) : any {
    return value[arg];
  } and the others I've no clue how to check. Let's follow the thread. but ty !

Answer (score 1):

This issue has also been reported in: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8704

If you have the following situation:

*component A depends on service B which depends on service C*,

the solution is to add **@Injectable()** to service B and also add services B and C to the providers list of component A.

(An alternative solution is to add a forwardRef to service C in the constructor of service B, using **@Inject(forwardRef(() => ServiceC)** and also add services B and C to the providers list of component A)

Comment: I will try and test this solution 'til tomorrow..and I will let you know indeed. Crossing the fingers

Comment: Not my scenario, Hans ! (sorry for the late response).

Comment: @Inject(forwardRef(() => ServiceC) 

parenthesis do not match.

Comment: I am facing same issue as mentioned in above
I have added all service (A,B,C) in provider of @NgModule so Is @Inject(forwardRef(() => ServiceC) required to add?
I have tried to add above but still facing issue

Answer (score 1):

For me, taking out the localStorage from providers: from 
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, localStorage]
to
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]

fixed the issue. I am almost certain I witnessed it working with localStorage bug maybe it was a mirage.

Just make sure that you don't confuse directives: with providers:

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure why my error disappeared, but after i removed the arguments from my service constructors and threw the import directly like below it worked

```
import {blindMen} from '../elephant'
...
export class ElephantComponet{
blindMen:any;
constructor(){
this.blindMen = blindMen;
    }
}
```