# Angular 2 OpaqueToken results as null (RC6)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I've read pretty much everything on the internet available about opaque tokens, and don't think I could be doing this more by the book.

Functionality I want:

I have a constants object. I want that object to be injectable application-wide.

```
export const Constants = {...key/vals...}
```

Very simple.
I create an OpaqueToken to allow me to make this Constant object injectable:

```
import {OpaqueToken} from '@angular/core';
export const AppConstants = new OpaqueToken('AppConstants');
```

Also very simple.

In my root module definition, I import both the OpaqueToken and my Constants object, and place them into the providers array using a map literal:

```
import {Constants} from '....';
import {AppConstants} from '....';

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        {provide: AppConstants, useValue: Constants}
    ],
    ...
})
```

Okay awesome. Now, in any of my imported modules, if I'm understanding the whole 'services are globally available' thing, I should be able to do the following:

```
import {AppConstants} from '.....';

@Injectable()
export class MyCoolClass {
    constructor(@Inject(AppConstants) private constants:any) {
    }

    someMethod(){
        let myVar = this.constants['someValue'];
    }
}
```

This compiles fine (I'm using Webpack). However, at runtime I get:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./App class App_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'someValue' of null
```

Obviously, this has been simplified so you can read it easier, but I'm literally just switching variable names.

What do I not understand about DI here? OpaqueToken was supposed to be the thing that addresses the issue of injecting fixed values into constructors, I thought, and I thought that @Inject was the way to do it.

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting `null` returned for the value of my Constants object?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks ok, at least the part that concerns OpaqueToken. Any way, there are no valid reasons for `null`. Are there no other errors that would prevent normal execution? Can you recreate the issue on plunker with SystemJS? See also [this check list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37166080/3731501).

Comment: Okay, so, this is the issue that I've been having with (webpack? Angular?) -- barrel imports don't work "all the time". I changed my import statements to explicit, full-path imports and it worked. 
This is something I've found from time to time (probably 30-50% of the time) where barrel imports won't work in certain cases, with no apparent rhyme or reason.
Hmmm..... Anyhow, fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so, this is the issue that I've been having with (webpack? Angular?) -- barrel imports don't work "all the time". I changed my import statements to explicit, full-path imports and it worked. This is something I've found from time to time (probably 30-50% of the time) where barrel imports won't work in certain cases, with no apparent rhyme or reason. Hmmm.....

Anyhow, fixed.